# How to check if Oracle Data Access Components is already installed?

Tags: windows, oracle, odac

How to check if  Oracle Data Access Components is installed and version on my computer?

Also How to check if Oracle Data Provider is installed and version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "official" way is to use the `opatch lsinventory` command (see [Lsinventory Command for OUI-based Oracle Homes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/em.111/b31207/oui7_opatch.htm#CEGGIHCF)) but you could also check the version of the DLLs.